# Javascript copy function do not work on input type?

Tags: javascript

I tryed to keep copy but it do not copy the value of input..

what is wrong in this java code when click on `<p>...</p>` its copy perfect but not working perfect when click on
`<input>...</input>` we want perfect copy at .. somebody has a solution?

```js
function copyFunction(t) {
  var r = document.createElement("textarea");
  r.value = t
  , document.body.appendChild(r)
  , r.select()
  , document.execCommand("Copy")
  , r.remove()
}
$(document).on("click", ".fancy-text", function() {
  copyFunction($(this).find("p").text())
  , $(this).append('<span class="copied">Copied...</span>')
  , $(".copied").fadeOut(3e3)
}), 
function myFunction() {
   var dots     = document.getElementById("dots");
   var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
   var btnText  = document.getElementById("myBtn");
   
   if (dots.style.display === "none") {
     dots.style.display     = "inline";
     btnText.innerHTML      = "Read more";
     moreText.style.display = "none";
   } else {
     dots.style.display     = "none";
     btnText.innerHTML      = "Read less";
     moreText.style.display = "inline";
   }
}
```

```css
.fancy-text {
  position     : relative;
  border-style : solid;
  border-color : #f1f1f1;
  overflow     : hidden;
  }
.fancy-text p {
  padding            : 10px;
  margin             : 0;
  font-size          : 20px;
  cursor             : pointer;
  -webkit-transition : .3s;
  transition         : .3s;
  overflow           : hidden;
  }
```

```html
<div class="fancy-text">
  <p>One</p>
</div>


<div class="fancy-text">
  <input type="text" id="bubble" value="webbox" class="line">
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try understanding the function and you will understand why it doesn't work with input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you currently have and it works for elements with paragraphs:

```
copyFunction($(this).find("p").text())
```

If you want it to work with input field you need to use the following:

```
copyFunction($(this).find("input").val())
```

You will need to add some extra logic in your code to recognise the type of element it is copying from and calling the copyFunction with the appropriate text/value parameter.